# Image.FromStream() method returns Invalid Argument exception

Tags: c#, .net, image, exception, memorystream

I am capturing images from a smart camera imager and receiving the byte array from the camera through socket programming (.NET application is the client, camera is the server).

The problem is that i get System.InvalidArgument exception at runtime.

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray) 
{
    if(byteArray != null) 
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return Image.FromStream(ms, false, false); 
        /*last argument is supposed to turn Image data validation off*/
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have searched this problem in many forums and tried the suggestions given by many experts but nothing helped.

I dont think there is any problem with the byte array as such because When i feed the same byte array into my VC++ MFC client application, i get the image. But this doesn't somehow work in C#.NET.

Can anyone help me ?

P.S :

Other methods i've tried to accomplish the same task are:

1.

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
    if(byteArray != null) 
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        ms.Position = 0; 
        return Image.FromStream(ms, false, false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

2.

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray) 
{
    if(byteArray != null) 
    {
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
        Bitmap b = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(byteArray);
        return b;
    }
    return null;
}
```

None of the above methods worked. Kindly help.

Comment: What happens if you simply write the bytearray to a file on disk? Is the file open-able with something like photoshop?

Comment: have you solved it? I have the same problem

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 10):

`Image.FromStream()` expects a stream that contains ONLY one image!

It resets the stream.Position to 0. I've you have a stream that contains multiple images or other stuff, you have to read your image data into a byte array and to initialize a **MemoryStream** with that:

```
Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(myImageByteArray));
```

The **MemoryStream** has to remain open as long as the image is in use.

I've learned that the hard way, too.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the image is embedded in an OLE field and you have to consider the 88 bytes OLE header plus payload:

```
byteBlobData = (Byte[]) reader.GetValue(0);
stream = new MemoryStream(byteBlobData, 88, byteBlobData.Length - 88);
img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: In my case, I only had to "remove" 8 bytes. new MemoryStream(byteBlobData, 8, byteBlobData.Length - 8);

Comment: How could you know it was 8 bits long?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that something is going wrong when receiving the file from the server. Perhaps you're only getting part of the file before trying to convert it to an `Image`? Are you *sure* it's the exact same byte array you're feeding the C++ application?

Try saving the stream to a file and see what you get. You might be able to uncover some clues there.

You can also add a breakpoint and manually compare some of the bytes in the byte array to what they're supposed to be (if you know that).

---

Edit: It looks like there's nothing wrong with receiving the data. The problem is that it's in raw format (not a format that `Image.FromStream` understands). The [`Bitmap(Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx) may be of use here. Or, you can create the blank bitmap and blt it manually from the raw data.

Comment: Hello,

I tried saving the image to a jpg, bmp file but i don't get the picture in the file.

What is puzzling is that it is with the same byte array that i am able to display image in my VC++ MFC application.

Comment: That's why I'm not so sure it's the same byte array. Are the file sizes the same?

Comment: The VC++ application displays live images from the camera and therefore what i did was writing the byte array to a txt file. Similarly, from my .NET appln i wrote the byte array to a file nad then compared these two files. I find that all the values are filled and they are more or less the same.

Comment: Infact, i tried feeding the array i got from VC++ application (in txt file) to my C#.NET application. This failed too :-(

Comment: The byte array will not be same everytime due to intensity fluctuations of light falling on camera's lens. So, what i observed was some minor variations in byte array values between VC++ log and C# log

Comment: Maybe your C++ code just paint the camera's captured image directly on the screen, so it is not a formatted image (e.g. Jpg, png, bmp, etc), hence Image.FromStream could not work

Comment: The camera send raw data which is of no format(no compression).

Comment: Hello Michael,

Yes, you are right. The image array is not formatted. How do i proceed in that case ? Please help

Comment: Btw, is it a text file, as in ascii-readable text? Or just .txt file extension? Also try to check the file marker, if it is indeed a valid image format

Comment: Try copy paste, i tried that approach with the raw image i get from camera in vb6 using winapi component, luckily the vb6 image control has paste method. Maybe .net image control has paste method too

Comment: Hi Michael Buen,
It is just a .txt file extension with byte array values in human readable format.
What is this copy paste approach using winapi component ? Could you kindly elaborate in little more detail since i am not aware of it ?

Comment: try this:  http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/93476-Programatically-Using-A-Webcam-In-C/ using api from windows built-in avicap32.dll http://weblogs.asp.net/nleghari/articles/webcam.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem when doing this:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
screenshot.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Save(bytes, 0, steam.Length);
```

With the last 2 lines being the problem.  I fixed it by doing this:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
screenshot.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

And then this worked:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.InvalidArgument` means The stream does not have a valid image format, i.e. an image type that is not supported.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the reply.

But how come the same byte array works in my VC++ MFC application ?

Also is there any way i could check the validity of my byte array image data ?

Arvind K

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] item)
{          
   Image img=Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(item)); 
   img.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
   return img;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in the past and it was caused by a leak within the windows GDI libraries, which is what 'Bitmap' uses. If this happening all the time for you then its probably unrelated, however.

Comment: Hello Chris,

Thanks for the reply.

It happens to me everytime i run the code.

Answer (score 0):

**this code is working**

```
        string query="SELECT * from gym_member where Registration_No ='" + textBox9.Text + "'";

        command = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][18];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        ms.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something similar to what is described here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de9ee1c9-16d3-4422-a99f-e863041e4c1d/reading-raw-rgba-data-into-a-bitmap

```
Image ImageFromRawBgraArray(
    byte[] arr, 
    int charWidth, int charHeight,
    int widthInChars, 
    PixelFormat pixelFormat)
{
    var output = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var bmpData = output.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, output.PixelFormat);

    // Row-by-row copy
    var arrRowLength = width * Image.GetPixelFormatSize(output.PixelFormat) / 8;
    var ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(arr, i * arrRowLength, ptr, arrRowLength);
        ptr += bmpData.Stride;
    }

    output.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**After load from DataBase byteArray has more byte than one image.** In my case it was 82.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(byteArray, 82, byteArray.Length - 82);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

And for save in the DB I insert 82 byte to begin stream. `Properties.Resources.ImgForDB` - it is binary file that contain those 82 byte. (I get it next path - Load Image from DB to MemoryStream and save to binary file first 82 byte. You can take it here - https://yadi.sk/d/bFVQk_tdEXUd-A)

```
        MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        if (path != "")
        {
            Image.FromFile(path).Save(temp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Write(Properties.Resources.ImgForDB, 0, Properties.Resources.ImgForDB.Length);
            ms.Write(temp.ToArray(), 0, temp.ToArray().Length);

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Someone (first, Second, Third) values (@a,@b,@c)", connP);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", fio);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", post);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", ms.ToArray());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I don't think that help in this case.

Comment: I has the same problem. And it helped me.