# Varbinary max image

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, coolite, ext.net

I am storing images in database in a `varbinary(max)` field.

I am try to show an image on my form. I've tried many different ways but it did not show it.

This is my Code:

```
//I am adding an image in my form
Ext.Net.Image image = new Ext.Net.Image();
image.ID = "imgShow";

FormLayout1.Items.Add(image);

byte[] buffer = q.TckLogo;
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

// it is giving error because of FromStream
image.items.Add(Image.FromStream(memStream));
```

How can I display my image in my form?

I am using Ext.Net (Coolite).

Comment: In this line -> image.Controls.Add(Image.FromStream(memStream)); Ext.Net.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'

Comment: Check out also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676072/image-fromstream-method-returns-invalid-argument-exception/1633907#1633907

Answer (score 4):

In a web application, image controls have an `ImageUrl` property pointing to some server side script which will return the image. I am not familiar with `Ext.Net.Image` but I suppose that you need to use a http handler to serve the image:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var id = context.Request["id"];
        byte[] imageData = FetchImageFromDb(id);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

and then have your image control point to this generic handler:

```
Ext.Net.Image image = new Ext.Net.Image();
image.ID = "imgShow";
// pass some id to the generic handler which will 
// allow it to fetch the image from the database
// and stream it to the response
image.ImageUrl = "~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=123"; 
FormLayout1.Items.Add(image);
image.items.Add(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear to me what Ext.Net is here, or why you are using it, but the FromStream usage suggests you are confusing is with [`System.Drawing.Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx); however, event that is moot as you **shouldn't use** System.Drawing from a web app. If you are just trying to return an image to the client, you shouldn't have to process it *at all* in many cases - just throw the BLOB down the wire to the client.

Unrelated, but as Jon notes you're also trying to read from the end of a MemoryStream.